# In PyCharm, is it possible to concatenate text into an existing environment variable by pasting?

Tags: pycharm, environment-variables

I want to add a new directory, `/dir3` to the end of my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in PyCharm.

At first it looks like this:

[image: Before]

Then, I copied ':/dir3' to my clipboard, and when I enter "edit mode" and paste the value, it just overwrites the whole thing:

[image: After]

And it doesn't matter if I try to add it to the end or to the beginning of the current value - it ALWAYS overwrites the whole current value.

So is it possible to paste into an environment variable without having the previous value overwritten?

Comment: this is bothering me too!